# change password in asp.net,c#,ms-access database

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, ms-access-2007

i am desiging a change password screen in asp.net,c#,MS-access database 
 i m having  4 fields 
userid,
oldpassword,
newpassword 
confirm password

NOW I M NOT GETTING RESULT THE COUNT RETURNS 0  I HAVE UPDATED MY CODE

my code is as follows

```
      try

      {

      OleDbConnection myCon = new  OleDbConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["vhgroupconnection"]
       .ConnectionString);
        myCon.Open();

        string userid = txtuserid.Text;
        string oldpass = txtoldpass.Text;
        string newPass = txtnewpass.Text;
        string conPass = txtconfirmpass.Text;

        string q = "select user_id,passwd from register where user_id = @userid and       passwd = @oldpass";

        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(q, myCon);



        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userid", txtuserid.Text);

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@oldpass", txtoldpass.Text);

      OleDbDataReader re = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        re.Read();

        if (re["user_id"].ToString() != String.Empty && re["passwd"].ToString() != String.Empty)
        {
            if (newPass.Trim() != conPass.Trim())
            {
                lblmsg.Text = "New Password and old password does not match";

            }
            else
            {
               q = "UPDATE register SET  passwd = @newPass WHERE user_id =@userid";
                cmd = new OleDbCommand(q, myCon);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userid", txtuserid.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@newPasss", txtnewpass.Text);



                int count = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                if (count > 0)
                {
                    lblmsg.Text = "Password changed successfully";
                }
                else
                {
                    lblmsg.Text = "password not changed";
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
```

plz help me to solve the error

Answer (score 2):

You're getting the error, `No constructor is defined`, because you can't directly instantiate this object.  As stated on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbdatareader.aspx):

> To create an OleDbDataReader, you must call the ExecuteReader method
>   of the OleDbCommand object, instead of directly using a constructor.

Essentially, you'd do something like the following after creating your connection and specifying your query:

```
OleDbDataReader re = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Comment: i tried it but when i debugged the code it showed exception as ex {"No value given for one or more required parameters."} System.Exception {System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException}

Comment: I GOt the answer i changed my update query as: q = "UPDATE register SET passwd = '"+txtnewpass.Text+"' WHERE user_id ='"+txtuserid.Text+"'"; it worked successfully thank you for your help